# Which mailgun library should be used for migrating Parse hosted app to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-platform, package.json

I need to migrate the current Parse hosted Cloud code to my Heroku app.

It seems there are a few mailgun libraries for Node.JS, e.g. mailgun and mailgun-js. I am just wondering which is the one the current api.parse.com uses. I will need to migrate my Cloud code and use a proper mailgun library for transactional emails.

An example of the dependencies in package.js would be really helpful.

My current Cloud code hosted on api.parse.com looks like:

```
var Mailgun = require('mailgun');
Mailgun.initialize(MG_DOMAIN, MG_KEY);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that the mailgun dependencies are in the package.json, make sure you add --save to the end of your npm install.  For example:

npm install mailgun-js --save

this should do the trick to make sure heroku installs the dependencies on deploy